# ERROR File upload using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to upload image and send it to database but it's not working.
and when I tried again to var_dump
this is the output:

```
array(1) {
    ["upload"]=> array(5) {
        ["name"]=> string(9) "error.jpg"
        ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
        ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php8E94.tmp"
        ["error"]=> int(0)
        ["size"]=> int(82805)
    }
}
```

This is my code:

```
  <?php

include ('includes/config.php');

$mysqli =  new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_UNAME,DB_PASSWD,DB_NAME);

if($mysqli->connect_errno){

    echo "MYSQLI connect error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}";
    die();
}



if(isset($_POST['addbtn'])){


$itemcode  = $_POST['icode'];
$itemname  = $_POST['iname'];
$brandname = $_POST['brandname'];
$upload    = basename ($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$path = "img/";

  if(!empty($upload)){
        $i1 = strrpos($upload,".");
        if (!$i1) { return ""; }
        $l1 = strlen($upload) - $i1;
        $ext1 = substr($upload,$i1+1,$l1);
        $ext1 = strtolower($ext1);
        $news_name1=time()+(1).'.'.$ext1;
        $newname1 = $path.$news_name1;
        $copied1 = copy($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $newname1);


    }else{
        $news_name1 = '';



    }

$iadd = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table_item (`itemcode`,`itemname`,`brandname`,`upload`) VALUES ('".$itemcode."', '".$itemname."','".$brandname."','".$news_name1."')  ");
$iadd->execute();
$iadd->close();
$mysqli->close();

var_dump($_FILES);

}

?>
```

Comment: check your max file upload limit on php.ini

Comment: You're not uploading your file to the database. You're just saving its FILENAME in the database. You are also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, have no upload verification code, no any DB error handling code.

Comment: P.S. Use `move_uploaded_file()` instead of `copy()`.

Comment: So, what's "not working"?  What are you trying to do?  What is it doing?  What is it not doing?  How do you know it's "not working"?

Comment: i checked max upload
upload_max_filesize=2M
max_file_uploads=20
that's is correct?

@RocketHazmat when i tried to submit the three items is inserted to the database but to image are not 
what is the problem?

thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Your var_dump says "file is already managed". Also, you say the database recording works (which is your last statement), so whatever the problem is, it doesn't generate errors traceable to php. So you don't have an error or is not an error for php.

1. Run your program and Check in `C:\xampp\tmp\` if a file is created & deleted.
2. Verify you are looking in the CORRECT `img/` directory.

PS As rocket-hazmat says, use `move_uploaded_file()` instead of `copy()`.